# Why is the coremata of Creatonotos gangis huge?

Tags: evolution, entomology, lepidoptera

This Australian moth has been some kind of curse image online due to its scent organs (coremata). It is inflated to attract mates. However, why does the coremata have to be inflated for it to work, and why does it have to be so big?
[image]